# Ubuntu как посмотреть ответы терминала

Tags: ubuntu

Мне нужно посмотреть ответы от терминала при выполнении команд, bash_history показывает только мои запросы а ответы к ним нет, знаю как то настраивают терминал что при перезапуске он хранит вводы-выводы терминала. Подскажите как посмотреть выводы из терминала, и сохранять эти значения в терминале при перезагрузке

Answer (score 1):

для этого есть специальная утилита **script**, да так и называется. С помощью неё можно записывать **stdin** и **stdout** терминала в файл, но для этого её нужно предварительно запустить, а по окончании закрыть.

Простой пример:

```
$ script log.txt
$ # какие-то действия
$ # ...
$ exit
$ 
$ cat log.txt
```